# Firefox "onerror" would not fire even when image is not valid

Tags: javascript, firefox, mime-types

I have a onerror handler on the image tag to handle switching when the remote image is not found.

the problem is that for certain broken remote images, it does not work.

http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/522455109/calvin-and-hobbessm_normal.jpg

```
<img onerror="this.src='/images/pic_not_found.png'" src="http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/522455109/calvin-and-hobbessm_normal.jpg">
```

Image below: 
1) when remote image found, 2) remote image not found (onerror not triggered) , 3) remote image not found (onerror triggered)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a broken link.

The `twimg.com` actually returns an image with the name of the url you requested.

just click your link to the image. It is not text what you are seeing, it is an image.

**Update**

Here is some code that works in all browsers.
It does some basic feature detection.

```
function handle( elem, img, state )
{
  if ((typeof(elem.onerror) === 'function' && state === 'fail') 
      || (elem.width === 0)
    )
     {
       elem.src = img;
     }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VVcQj/1

It uses both `onload` and `onerror`, but requires a function defined in javascript to handle the situation.

Comment: It is broken for me. are we looking at the same thing? http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/522455109/calvin-and-hobbessm_normal.jpg

Comment: @ming,  .. but the `onload` error works for me for this particular image.. http://jsfiddle.net/nenwQ/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/nenwQ  - works in chrome, not in firefox. Weird huh!

Comment: Hey Gaby, thanks a lot! This is amazingly smart! However, Chrome throws an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" for the function when I define it. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @ming i can only reproduce the error you mention when i mismatch `'` around the strings inside the `onerror=..` or `onload=...`

Comment: Thanks a lot gabe! it was an weird error with chrome - i moved the function downwards, and things worked well. Thanks a MILLION!

Comment: @ming, glad you got it sorted out :)

Comment: Thanks to you. =) it is interesting how minute the differences in browsers can be